# IntelliJ DSL plugin provide completion of Java classes and methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm attempting to write an IntelliJ plugin for a DSL which references Java classes and methods. The DSL is exposed in `*.conf` files within a Java project. A typical snippet of the DSL looks like this:

```
TASK taskClass=com.example.Foo taskMethod=someMethod;
```

I've been working through the IJ 'Simple' plugin tutorial to learn about plugins and am able to implement a fair bit of my own plugin. Currently, however, I'm stuck on trying to understand how I can provide auto-completion for the `taskClass` and `taskMethod` keywords. Having worked through the Simple tutorial all my completion shows is 'Hello'. Now I want to be able to extend my `CompletionContributor` to show java classes and methods that exist in the project. This doesn't seem to be addressed in the tutorial, but perhaps I'm just missing it.

What do I need, in order to do this? I would guess that there is already some cached info about all the existing java code in a project that my Contributor could leverage.

Comment: Try asking at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4408350276754-IntelliJ-DSL-plugin-provide-completion-of-Java-classes-and-methods

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [existing](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/0e2aa4030ee763c9b0c828f0b5119f4cdcc66f35/java/java-indexing-impl/src/com/intellij/psi/impl/java/stubs/index) [stub indices](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/stub-indexes.html).
For example, to get all class names in your project, you can use

```
val classNames = JavaFullClassNameIndex.getInstance().getAllKeys(project)
```

When using indices - your own or already existing ones - it is often useful to use the [Index Viewer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13029-index-viewer) plugin so you can have a look at which things are in which index.
To add it as a dependency of your plugin (so you don't have to install it manually each time you build your plugin) add the following to `intellij` block of your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins.set(listOf("java", "com.jetbrains.hackathon.indices.viewer:1.19"))
```

It should appear as a tool window on the right.
Don't forget to remove it once you are done with debugging the indices.

---

I also found the [PsiShortNamesCache](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/0e2aa4030ee763c9b0c828f0b5119f4cdcc66f35/java/java-indexing-api/src/com/intellij/psi/search/PsiShortNamesCache.java) which might be useful.